# while parsing a block collection expected <block end>, but found '?'

Tags: sql, dbt

I'm having this error and cant figure out whats going on

```
Raw Error:
    ------------------------------
    while parsing a block collection
      in "<unicode string>", line 4, column 5:
            - name: adventure_works_elt
            ^
    expected <block end>, but found '?'
      in "<unicode string>", line 5, column 5:
            description: 
            ^
```

Here's the code:

version: 1

```
sources:
    - name: adventure_works_elt
    description: 
    tables:
        - name: SalesOrderHeader
        description:
        - name: Product
        description:
        - name: ProductCategory
        description:
        - name: ProductSubcategory
        description:
        - name: ProductListPriceHistory
        description:
        - name: Address
        description:
        - name: StateProvince
        description:
        - name: CountryRegion
        description:
        - name: SalesOrderHeaderSalesReason
        description:
        - name: Person
        description:
        - name: SalesReason
        description:
```

Answer (score 1):

With YAML dictionaries you need to line up the keys like so:

```yaml
sources:
    - name: adventure_works_elt
      description: ""
      tables:
        - name: SalesOrderHeader
          description: ""
        - name: Product
          description: ""
        - name: ProductCategory
          description: ""
        - name: ProductSubcategory
          description: ""
        - name: ProductListPriceHistory
          description: ""
        - name: Address
          description: ""
        - name: StateProvince
          description: ""
        - name: CountryRegion
          description: ""
        - name: SalesOrderHeaderSalesReason
          description: ""
        - name: Person
          description: ""
        - name: SalesReason
          description: ""
```

Note the quotes I added as well, you’ll need those to avoid another error.